# House keeping files using for loop in bash script

Tags: bash

I have X directory along with many subdirectories ,again each subdirectory have some directories.
These directories have may files and they are generating every day.
We need to remove these files older than 90 days.
I am trying to write script with for loop but stuck in middle. below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/soainfra/shared/ControlDir/ftp/temp_ftp

cd $path

#filesize=`find . -mtime +900 -exec ls  {} \;`
filesize=`du -sm * -print 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -2|cut -f2`





for val in $filesize
do
#   cd '$val'
#   echo $val

    if [ -d "$val" ]
       then
           cd "$path/$val"
            echo $(du -sm *|sort -rn |head -5 |cut -f2)
     fi
done
```

Comment: you could try to use the -maxdepth n when using `find` couple with -mtime. I believe it's 90 instead of 900 if you're looking for files older than 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are tying to do it by using a loop, but with the line that you have commented it should work if you add the **-maxdepth** flag.

```
#!/bin/bash

path=/soainfra/shared/ControlDir/ftp/temp_ftp


find $path -maxdepth 1 -mtime +90 -delete
```

On the other hand, if you need to do it by a loop, be sure that the control command that you are running (**du -sm * -print 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -2|cut -f2**) is returning values.